# Multiprocessing Error with Results

Tags: python, function, class, multiprocessing, pool

I have a small problem in a big program, so I made a small example, which shows my problem:

```
import multiprocessing

class class1():
    def classfunction1(self, a):
        self.x = a

class class2():
    def classfunction2(self, a):
        self.y = a

def test(i):
    print("I'm in the Testfunction")
    b = i * class1.x * class2.y

    return b

class1 = class1()
class2 = class2()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = 1
    y = 2
    class1.classfunction1(x)
    class2.classfunction2(y)
    print("This variable is callable", class1.x)
    print("And this one is also callable", class2.y)
    counter = []
    for i in range(10):
        counter.append(i)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    results = pool.imap(test, counter)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    #resultslist = list(results)
```

When I use the last line `resultslist = list(results)` I get the follow Error:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback:
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\example2.py", line 24, in test
    b = i * class1.x * class2.y
AttributeError: 'class1' object has no attribute 'x'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\example2.py", line 43, in <module>
    resultslist = list(results)
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 695, in next
    raise value
AttributeError: 'class1' object has no attribute 'x'
```

It is necessary that the commands `class1.classfunction1(x)` and `class2.classfunction2(y)` are in the `if__name__=="__main__"`.
I need the basic structure of this script, so please don't do too many changes (if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to access the `x` attribute of the `class1` instance of `class1`(!) that has never been created in the worker subprocesses because `class1.classfunction1()` isn't called in them.

To fix that issue I added an `init()` function and call it both in the main process and specify it as the `initializer` function for each of the subprocesses created by the `Pool`:

```
import multiprocessing

class class1():
    def classfunction1(self, a):
        self.x = a

class class2():
    def classfunction2(self, a):
        self.y = a

def test(i):
    print("I'm in the Testfunction")
    b = i * class1.x * class2.y

    return b

def init():  # added
    global class1, class2
    class1 = class1()
    class2 = class2()
    x = 1
    y = 2
    class1.classfunction1(x)
    class2.classfunction2(y)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    init()  # explicit call here
    print("This variable is callable", class1.x)
    print("And this one is also callable", class2.y)
    counter = []
    for i in range(10):
        counter.append(i)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(initializer=init, processes=4)  # implicit call
    results = pool.imap(test, counter)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    resultslist = list(results)
    print(resultslist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked on my machine python 2.7.10

```
  ('This variable is callable', 1)
  ('And this one is also callable', 2)
  I'm in the Testfunction
  I'm in the Testfunction
  I'm in the Testfunction
  I'm in the Testfunction
  I'm in the Testfunction
  I'm in the Testfunction
  I'm in the Testfunction
  I'm in the Testfunction
  I'm in the Testfunction
  I'm in the Testfunction

 [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Comment: Didn't work on my Windows machine with Python 2.7.12. Your answer should be a comment, not an answer, in my option.

Comment: Not enough reputation to add comment under your question.

Comment: Then perhaps you should wait until your reputation is high enough,,, It may have worked for you because you're using a different OS (I'm guessing).